# Correct sample output but not getting accepted on codechef

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve this beginner problem using Python language: https://www.codechef.com/problems/ZUBTRCNT

I have written the code that gives the correct output on sample case. It gives the same output as other accepted answers. But my code is not getting accepted.

For reference:
(My code that is not accepted): https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/40506063

```
case=int(input())
for c in range(case):
    l,k=map(int,input().split())
    n = l - k + 1
    sum = n * (n + 1) // 2
    print("Case {}:".format(c+1),sum)
```

(Another persons successful answer): https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/39844942

```
t=int(input())
for i in range(0,t):
   l,k=map(int,input().split())
   if(l<k):
      print("Case "+str(i+1)+":","0")
   else:
      m=l-k+1
      m=m*(m+1)//2
      print("Case "+str(i+1)+":",m)
```

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you missed an important test case where `l<k`.

Have a look at the following code, which has an **Accepted** verdict on Codechef:

```
case=int(input())
for c in range(case):
    l,k=map(int,input().split())
    if(l<k):
      print("Case {}:".format(c+1),0)
    else:
        n = l - k + 1
        sum = n * (n + 1) // 2
        print("Case {}:".format(c+1),sum)
```

**Verdict:**

[image]

Comment: Oh. Thank for the help. I just noticed that coincidentally in all my test cases n was coming 0. And I was thinking I was getting the right answer.